# (c++)can u nest namespaces from extern sources

Tags: c++, nested, namespaces

i have a few headers with namespaces which all follow a certain namepattern

right now they all have a prefix infront of their actual name such as

```
namespace Xname{//inside name.h
  //stuff here
};
namespace Xsomething{//inside something.h
  //stuff here
};
```

now this works pretty good for my usage atm, but my idea is to create one more header that contains a namespace that would collect all the other namespaces so i can access them like so:

```
#include "mainheader.h"
X::name::stuff
X::something::stuff
```

this way i would just change the namespace name for new headers in the future like so

```
X::name::stuff
hello::name::stuff
```

i **cant** nest them like this:

```
namespace x{
   namespace something{
     //stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the new namespaces inside each other [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/xE6ExYvjf)

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Xname{//inside name.h
  const int x = 0;
};
namespace Xsomething{//inside something.h
  const int y = 1;
};

// Your other header
namespace X {
namespace name = Xname;
namespace something = Xsomething;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << X::name::x << "\n";
  std::cout << X::something::y << "\n";
}
```

Comment: yep this works thank you very much :D was playing around with the idea of assigning one namespace to another namespace but i got some errors, dunno why it didnt work at first.

Comment: Nice that it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the `using namespace` directive for this. Here is an example:

```cpp
namespace Xname {
    struct foo {};
}

namespace X {
    namespace name {
        using namespace Xname;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Xname::foo f1;       // original
    
    X::name::foo f2;     // alternative
}
```